# Is there a function for telling time in pyglet?

Tags: python, pyglet

I would like to be able to somehow tell the time in pyglet, either by the actual clock time or time since the program was launched kind of like pygames pygame.time.get_ticks().

The pyglet wiki says:

```
from pyglet import clock
while True:
    dt = clock.tick()
    # ... update and render ...
    print 'FPS is %f' % clock.get_fps()
```

The dt value returned gives the number of seconds (as a float) since the last “tick”.

The get_fps function averages the framerate over a sliding window of approximately 1 second. (You can calculate the instantaneous framerate by taking the reciprocal of dt).

But im not sure what they mean with "instantaneous framerate" and i dont know what reciprocal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  python's [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module. e.g.

```
time.time()
```

> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number.

or

```py
time.perf_counter()
```

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration. It does include time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide.

---

In PyGlet there is the [`pyglet.clock`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/modules/clock.html#module-pyglet.clock) module

e.g. the FPS can be determined by

```py
pyglet.clock.get_fps()
```

See also [Keeping track of time](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/time.html)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I got an error saying time.clock() will be removed in python 3.8 and that i should use time.perf_counter or time.process_time. Which would you recommend?

Comment: @tuppen2 For a system-wide time use `time.perf_counter()`